# c6386 buffer overrun while writing

Tags: c, dynamic, allocation, buffer-overrun

> - Function Name: expandStack
> - Input: a pointer to a Stack type (Stack*)
> - Output: none
> - Function Operation: The function expands a stack

```
void expandStack(Stack* stack){

    //Check the stack and the array are allocated
    if (stack == NULL ||stack->content == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Allocating a new sized array (*2 from the previous)
    Element* expandedStack = (Element*)malloc(2 * (stack->size) * sizeof(Element));

    //Case malloc failed
    if (expandedStack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Malloc has failed in file 'stack.c', 'expandStack' function\n");
        return;
    }

    //Updating size field
    stack->size *= 2;

    //Copy values from the previous array to the new array allocated
    for (int i = 0; i <= stack->topIndex; i++)
    {
        expandedStack[i].c = stack->content[i].c;
    }

    //Free old array
    free(stack->content);

    //Point to the new array in the heap
    stack->content = expandedStack;

}
```

In this line: expandedStack[i].c = stack->content[i].c;
I get a "green warning" saying: "c6386 buffer overrun while writing to 'expandedStack': The writeable size is '2 * (stack->size) * sizeof(Element)' bytes, but '2' bytes might be written.

The thing is that the code works fine, it compiles.

Comment: What if stack->size = 0? I think this might be what the linter is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning that says that the buffer could be overrun and is trying to warn you to add some more checks in your production code. **It is not necessarily an error.** If you did overrun the buffer, you would have an exception during run time, which would say `Stack corruption around local variable ...`

Debug the program, and see if any exception like that comes up. If not, then you are not exceeding the buffer's bounds.

Comment: Ehh...you should be a bit more cautious than simply saying it works if it doesn’t come up. Memory corruption issues can be quite subtle and can break your program in surprising ways (that are very hard to debug or reproduce).

Comment: @nneonneo Point noted. I also saw your comment on the original question, and I had not thought about that initially. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the details of the error,
'size' could theoritically be 0 but the default value is 1 and it would never be 0.

I just added a check that size isn't 0 and it disappeared.

Thanks!