# How to properly use new and delete (to avoid buffer overflow problems)

Tags: c++

This is related to my previous question(now deleted) where I tried to implement a `std::vector` like data structure.
The following is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#define print(m) std::cout << m << std::endl

template<typename T>
class vector
{
private:
    unsigned int size = 0;
    unsigned int mem = 5;

    bool full()
    {
        return size == mem;
    }

    void allocate()
    {
        mem += 5;
        T* newData = new T[mem];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newData[i] = data[i];
        }
        delete[] data; //previous buffer deleted
        data = newData; //the newbuffer is assigned to the previous buffer
        //
    }
    
public:
    T* data = new T[mem];
    unsigned int Size() 
    { 
        return size;
    }

    void push_back(T data_)
    {
        if (!full())
        {
            data[size] = data_;
        }
        else
        { 
            allocate();
            data[size] = data_;
        }
        size++;
    }

public:
    T& operator [] (unsigned int index)
    {
        return data[index];
    }   
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> list;
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    print(list.Size() << '\n');
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list.Size(); i++)
        print(list[i]);
}
```

I was (and still am) getting the following warning.

```
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'newData':  the writable size is 'mem*4' 
bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.
```

I was told that this was happening because I didn't `delete[]` the previous buffer which caused memory leaks and warnings. But this time I am deleting the buffer in `allocate` method.

Also something else that I don't understand is if I add `delete[] newData` after the line `data = newData`, again in allocate method.

```
void allocate()
{
    //other ommited code
    data = newData;
    //I thought I was supposed to do "delete[] newdata;" at first because it deletes the 
    //temporary buffer used to allocate more memory but it caused problems 
    //so i removed it.
    delete[] newdata;
}
```

The result that is printed is gibberish. But I don't understand why since the data is already copied to `data` from `newData`. So why does deleting `newData` cause problems? What exactly is causing the warning and how do I fix it?

Comment: Tip: Don't name your class ```List```, to avoid confusion with ```std::list<T>```.

Comment: _"the data is already copied to `data` from `newData`"_ How so?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Doesn't `data = newData;` do that?

Comment: The warning seems spurious. For what it's worth, I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code shown. Looks OK to me.

Comment: No, `data=newData;` does not copy whatever `newData` points to into `data`. It merely sets one pointer to the other one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ahh I see. That explain that. So I removed `data = newData;` to avoid them pointing to the same memory location.. Now I am just doing `delete[] newData;` but the warning still isn't going away.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617660/c6386-buffer-overrun-while-writing

Comment: In that case **Warning C6386** seems to be an incorrect deduction of the code analyser. You should submit a defect to Microsoft with the above code, compiler version etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not a problem with your code but a false positive from the analyser.**

If you open the + next to the message in the **Error List** *(assuming you include Intellisense errors in it)*, the analyser will show the step it used to make the deduction.

You could tell the analyser that mem is greater than size using `_Analysis_assume_(mem >= size);`. There are other options to help the analyser make correct guess.

However, if you work on a large project and you get that kind of error after an update of Visual Studio that add a new analysis and have a lot of false positive, you might prefer to disable some analysis rules if you don't have known memory problems with your application.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/how-to-specify-additional-code-information-by-using-analysis-assume?view=msvc-160 for more information.

Alternatively, just after increasing `mem` you can add the following condition for the rest of the function:

```
if (mem > size) { ... }
```

Or even add an assertion:

```
assert(mem > size);
```

> It look like the analyser is not real time so adjusting the code might not immediatly remove the warning. Analysing the file using the **Analyser** menu of Visual Studio should works immediatly *(if the analyser is enabled as it seems that old analysis result can survive compilation and even rebuilding etc...)*.

An untested alternative would be to have a `allocate_if_full` function instead. As all required information would be in the same function, analyser might not be fooled.

**Using standard algorithm**

Also, if you use `std::copy` instead of hand-coded loop, that the analyser won't report a potential problem.